# during unpacking with tar hide the error message: 'tar: Removing leading `/' from member names' for archive created with --absolute-names

Tags: command-line, log, tar

It is not duplicate, [other](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59243/tar-removing-leading-from-member-names/205314#205314) questions on stackexchange are about getting rid of this message as archive is created.

Is it possible, given archive that was created with `-P` option (with leading `/')?

I have an archive created with "`--absolute-names`"  (`-P` option) - with leading /.

I want to unpack it, with / stripped (tar is doing it by default).

It is almost ideal, but I want to silence:

```
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names.
```

without removing other messages (so brute force in the form of `2>/dev/null` is not a solution).

I found multiple solution how to silence this message during creating archive but none for unpacking.
I know about `grep -v` but it will (a) hide error code from tar (b) add its own error code if message about / is not stripped.

This situation may be replicated with

```
cd /home/user/tmp
touch a.txt
mateusz@Grisznak:~/Desktop/tmp$ tar --create -P /home/user/tmp > a.tar
mateusz@Grisznak:~/Desktop/tmp$ tar --extract --file=a.tar
```

To avoid XY problem: I am unpacking archives created by `backup` gem (http://backup.github.io/backup/v4/).

Comment: Did you try using this `2>/dev/null` or `&>/dev/null` with `tar`?

Comment: @George I think the OP wants to make sure other error messages are not discarded, so that may not be the best option.

Comment: @George No, as it would silence all error messages. My goal is to get notification from cron about all errors and only errors.